# Is there a default block or widget instance that would give me a grid view listing of all my categories?

Tags: category

I would like to create a cms page that lists one item from each category and assembles it in a grid.

Right now Im using Images as anchors that route to specified category pages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show a specific product of the categories or a random one?

Check this link: http://www.jimcode.org/2011/03/magento-putting-products-cms-page-homepage/

{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Answer (score -1):

By one item if you mean product then refer to below links

From below link, you can refer to answer provided by programmer_rkt, he was provided details on how you can create your own list.phtml and pass category id from block..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253581/display-multiple-category-product-on-magento-homepage

http://www.hellothemes.com/support-category/magento-tutorials/show-category-products-homepage/

If you wanted to display all categories then refer to below articles, you will get idea on how to do this
This link provides step by step explanation on how showing categories of your store with images.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/how_to_create_categories_grid_list_with_images

http://www.magentoworks.net/display-store-categories-on-homepage-in-magento/

Comment: Though it answer the question, LINK ONLY ANSWERS should be avoided. Please provide a short description about what are this link do at least..Thanks

Comment: Sure..agreed, updated my answer...thanks for suggestion.

Comment: still it seems as link only answer. What I mean is that you just need to show a "screenshot" of these links here so that they will become valid even if links that you put here didnt work in future. Note : I didnt downvote you. It is some other community member

Comment: no problem, I am learning....will take care in future posts... :)

Comment: Yup. Dont be desp. Down votes are actually appreciations to become good teacher. I got a lot before and I am still getting. It's a good tool... Spread the Knowledge friend :)